# Sequelize: findAll with include where id is in a jsonb

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

Here is my query

```
Car.findAll({
  attributes: ['id'],
  include: [
    {
         model: Sedan,
         where: {
           id:{                    
                 [Op.in]: [sequelize.col('car.favorites')]
           }
         }
     }
  ]
})
```

I want to include all sadans where the "id" of the sadan matches one of the ids stored in the jsonb array "favorites" which is part of the "car" table.

Above is my attempt with many other but it doesn't seem to be able to read the jsonb column.

What's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do above?

Comment: What results does the query give you? What are you expecting to receive instead?

Comment: It may also be useful to check the SQL generated by Sequelize: `Car.findAll({ logging: console.log, attributes: //...`

Comment: I receive a 500 error with "name": "error",
            "length": 264,
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "code": "42883",
            "hint": "No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",

Comment: I'm expecting to receive a list of cars with only the sadans who's ids are in the jsonb array

Comment: Try replacing the `sequelize.col` with `sequelize.literal('car->favorites')` or `sequelize.literal('car->>favorites')`. Do try enabling the logging, let's see what the SQL query is.

Comment: My SQL query: SELECT "car"."id", "sedan"."id" AS "sedan.id", "sedan"."name" AS "sedan.name", "sedan"."images" AS "sedan.images", "sedan"."active" AS "sedan.active" FROM "cars" AS "car" LEFT OUTER JOIN "sedan" AS "sedan" ON "car"."id" = "sedan"."carId" AND "sedan"."id" IN ("car"."favorites") AND "car"."active" = true;
GET /page/lot/ 500 73.763 ms - 2189

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import Sequelize, { Op } from 'sequelize';
import assert from 'assert';

class Car extends Sequelize.Model {}
Car.init(
  {
    favorites: {
      type: Sequelize.JSONB,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Car' },
);

class Sedan extends Sequelize.Model {}
Sedan.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'Sedan' });

Car.hasMany(Sedan);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await Car.create({ favorites: [1, 5, 6], Sedans: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] }, { include: [Sedan] });

    const cars = await Car.findAll({
      attributes: ['id'],
      include: [
        {
          model: Sedan,
          where: {
            id: {
              [Op.in]: [Sequelize.literal(`select jsonb_array_elements_text(favorites)::integer from "Car"`)],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    assert(cars[0].Sedans.length === 1, 'The count of sedans is not correct');
    console.log(cars[0].Sedans);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

After saving seed data into the database, we have below data records:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Car";
 id | favorites
----+-----------
  1 | [1, 5, 6]
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Sedan";
 id | CarId
----+-------
  1 |     1
  2 |     1
(2 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Car" as c
node-sequelize-examples-# left join "Sedan" as s on c.id = s."CarId"
node-sequelize-examples-# where s.id in (select jsonb_array_elements_text(favorites)::integer from "Car");
 id | favorites | id | CarId
----+-----------+----+-------
  1 | [1, 5, 6] |  1 |     1
(1 row)
```

The raw SQL query like this:

```sql
select * from "Car" as c
left join "Sedan" as s on c.id = s."CarId"
where s.id in (select jsonb_array_elements_text(favorites)::integer from "Car")
```

The query result log as expected:

```sh
[ Sedan {
    dataValues: { id: 1, CarId: 1 },
    _previousDataValues: { id: 1, CarId: 1 },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: false,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: null,
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       sequelize: [Sequelize],
       hooks: {} },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: false,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       include: undefined,
       includeNames: undefined,
       includeMap: undefined,
       includeValidated: true,
       raw: true,
       attributes: undefined },
    isNewRecord: false } ]
```